# The set of linear independent vectors is an open set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In the space $\mathbb{R}^{2n} = \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ let $A$ be the set of pairs $(x,y) (x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $x,y$ are linearly independents, i.e., we have $x \neq \lambda y$ for all $\lambda$. Prove that $A$ is an open set.

This question is from "Elementos de Topologia Geral" (Elements of General Topology) by Elon Lages Lima, braziliam mathmatician.

My attempt (I want to know also if this attempt is "theoretically" correct): To show that $A$ is an open set in the metric space $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ we must have for all point $(a,b) \in A$ be the center of an open ball fully contained in $A$.
So, taking a point $(a,b)$, we create the open ball $B((a,b); r))$ and for some $(c,d) \in B((a,b); r))$ we have to find that $r$ to make $(c,d) \in A$. (Is this procedure correct?)

What I have to do? I don't know how to complete.

Comment: I guess you meant "we don't have $x = \lambda y$ for **some** $\lambda$" (or equivalently: "we have $x \neq \lambda y$ for all $\lambda$")? For you question: it might be easier to show that the complement is closed.

Comment: Your expansion of the condition is flawed. You would have $(x,0)$ in $A$ for all $x\neq 0$, even though the set $\{0,x\}$ is clearly linearly dependent. You need to also require $y\neq\lambda x$.

Comment: Your plan is logically incoherent. You cannot take $(c,d)\in B((a,b);r)$ if you haven't chosen $r$. And you have things backwards. You do not choose $r$ in terms of $(c,d)$. Given $(a,b)$, you need to find a single $r\gt0$ such that **every** $(c,d)\in B((a,b);r)$ is in $A$.

Comment: Still wrong. Again, consider $x\neq \textbf{0}$, and take the pair $(x,\mathbf{0})$. Should that element be in $A$? No. Does there exist a $\lambda$ such that $x=\lambda \mathbf{0}$? No. So you are saying that it **is** in $A$, even though it *shouldn't*.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Wait.. I have to change my text? And, I'll try more, I understand: I have to find the r>0 such that we have the ball contained in A.

Comment: Hint about the substance of the question, not your text. Think about the angle between two vectors in the plane that are linearly independent. How would you show a nearby pair of vectors is also linearly independent?

Comment: And that is not what you wrote. What you wrote was that you take the ball $B((a,b);r)$, without first specifying $r$ (which is nonsense), and then you pick an element $(c,d)$ in that ball, and then you try to find an $r$ such that $(c,d)$ lies in $A$... which is a lot of nonsense. Given $(a,b)\in A$, you need to find $r\gt 0$ such that for **every** $(c,d)\in B((a,b);r)$ you have $(c,d)\in A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elegant way to do this is to find a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $x$ and $y$ are linear independent if and only if $f(x,y)\ne 0.$ In that case $A=f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$ is open as the preimage of an open set.

Such a function is for example
$$
f(x,y) = |x_1y_2-x_2y_1|+|x_2y_3-x_3y_2|+\dots+|x_{n-1}y_n-x_ny_{n-1}|,
$$
where $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,\dots,y_n).$

Comment: This is correct, but probably at a level too high for the OP, who is learning the definitions.

Comment: You are probably right; but I did have a look at the book he mentioned, and this is exercise 10 on page 96, and there is quite a bit of fairly sophisticated material preceding it, so such a solution might have well been the intention of the book author.